# add script to google form generated by a script

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I have a google sheet that I use to define list of questions and I wrote a script that when I run it, it generated automatically a google form for me with the survey (I followed this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

I have 2 issues I am trying to find a solution:

1. I would like to trigger an event when a specific answer is selected (I am using s list item) - where can I configure this event?
2. I would like to add a script to be executed when the form is submitted, I understand that I can enter the form and go to script editor, but since I am generating the form automatically, it would be very comfortable for me if when I generate the form programmatic I would add the script for the events. Is it possible?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You can't trigger an event to run at the moment a Form question is answered.  You *could* have some code do something based on what an answer was to a question.  The only trigger for a live Google Form is the "On Submit Trigger".  There is no "built-in" way to have the Form dynamically change as the user is answering questions.  You could have the user submit a partial submission, build another form, send an email to the user, and have them open yet another form.  But I doubt you'd want to do that.  You could create a form with HTML, CSS and JavaScript with an Apps Script stand alone Web App.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I generate the on submit event from within a script that I use to generate this form?

Comment: You need to use `ScriptApp.newTrigger()`.  [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname)

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Hi, I managed to add onFormSubmit trigger, but is there a way to debug it?

Comment: You can "hard code" an example of what the input data would be, and run it in the script editor with the debugger.   Choose the function name from the drop down, and then click the icon of the bug.